# How I can add a keyword to gcc?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, keyword

My target is to analyze and learn in details of compiler development techniques. Here I want to add a keyword in gcc and see how it works.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add an entry to `c_common_reswords`, in [c-common.c](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/c-family/c-common.c?view=markup). You'll need to allocate a new RID_ constant for that, and process it according to the semantics you want to give it.